# login attempt with password incorrect in Artifactory

Tags: authentication, passwords, locking, artifactory

In Artifactory, when user login incorrect 5 times, it only lock 1 second, how can I increase this duration?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make this user locked until the Admin release it. This can be done by going to the Artifactory UI --> Admin --> Security Configuration --> User Locking --> And check the "Lock User After Exceeding Max Failed Login Attempts" checkbox.
I don't know if you can increase the time of the "temporary" lock.

Comment: I tried your suggest, but I afraid that admin account can be locked, then I have to restore system to get back admin account.

Comment: You are correct. Therefore I would suggest creating more than 1 Admin user. This will allow you to have the ability to unblock even the Admin user in case that it was blocked. 
Up to you.

Answer (score 3):

By default, Artifactory comes with a built-in embedded Derby database.

You can try using my method:

1. Install Derby (http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/install_software.html#derby_configure)
2. Go to location where you installed Artifactory
3. Stop Artifactory and then connect to Artifactory Database: (You can replace version of Artifactory with the version you have installed)

> java org.apache.derby.tools.ij
>
> ij> connect 'jdbc:derby:/opt/artifactory-oss-6.0.1/data/derby';

(In my case, "/opt/artifactory-oss-6.0.1" is install location)

4. Update admin user status from "blocked" to "enabled"

> ij> update access_users set STATUS='enabled' where username='admin';

Finally, disconnect the database and restart Artifactory.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped use to restore our admin account.
Only one small update is required in the answer. Before step 3, artifactory process needs to stopped otherwise step3 says "ERROR XSDB6: Another instance of Derby may have already booted the database"

Comment: The question was "*how can I increase [locking] duration*", so this this answer isn't exactly relevant (*though still useful*). As for unlocking, the item #4 (*the SQL query*) is already sufficient for those with database clients available (*`mysql`, `psql`, etc*), no need to install additional tools.